# How to Print a Tibble in R When it Groups Columns Automatically?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a tibble. When I use `view(df)`, I get the following output in a new window:

```
indicator.id  indicator.value  country.id  country.value  
POP.HI        Population       1A          Arab World
POP.HI        Population       1B          Armenia
```

But when I use `head(df)`, I get the following output:

```
          indicator                 country
        <data.frame>            <data.frame>
<data.frame [6 × 2]>    <data.frame [6 × 2]>    
<data.frame [6 × 2]>    <data.frame [6 × 2]>
```

So, `head(df)` seems to be combining the two indicator columns into one and the same for country. Is there a way to fix this so that I can print a bit of the tibble (like `view()`, but not in a new window)?

I've tried `print.data.frame(head(df))`, which almost works, but the output is quite messy and not in a nice scrollable table. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the columns 'indicator', 'country' are both 'data.frame'.  An option is to use `do.call` with `data.frame` to create a data.frame with 4 columns

```
df1 <- do.call(data.frame, df)
```

---

Another option is `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unnest_wider(c(indicator, country))
```

Comment: Perfect! And how can I just print e.g. the first 10 rows instead of the whole thing? `do.call(data.frame, df, n=10)` doesn't seem to work. @akrun

Comment: @HelpNeeded3 you need `df1 <- do.call(data.frame, df); head(df1, 10)`